Bitcoin wallet not synchronizing
I'm waiting for receiving bitcoins to my Bitcoin wallet app version 10.16.
They have been sent but will not appear in app because its not synchronizing.
At startup the a popup says "security varning your unit is old and insecure. Only use it for small amount."
At the bottom of the app it says synchronizing:storageissues.
What could i do? Could I add my receivingadress in another wallet and receive the fynds there?

It sounds like your device’s disk is full. Perhaps try to free some space?
